# Windows 10 keeps looping "How do you want to open this file?" dialog

Tags: windows, associations

1. I double click an xml file.
2. Windows 10 asks me "How do you want to open this file?"
3. I make a selection and click ok
4. I'm back at 2 (rince and repeat, forever...)

If I click the "always use" checkbox, I even see the icons refresh in the windows explorer, before the "How do you want to open this file?" dialog pops back in screen.

I already tried deleting all the xml keys in the registry that I could find (no worries, I exported them first).

I tried different programs in the dialog.
Nothing works.

I created a dummy file extension, and that worked fine... the dialog appeared once, and after that it opened in the app I picked.

But it looks like somehow the file open dialog is stuck on .xml files.

Does anyone have any clue at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found this:

Run / gpedit.msc (edit group policy)

locate and expand Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components now click on File Explorer

on the right panel, double click on "Do not show the 'new application installed' notification" and set it to "Enabled"

Comment: That does fix the issue.
Not sure if it disabled more then I would like, but at least I can double click the file now, and it opens up in my editor.

I did try to create a new file type, and double clicked that to see if the dialog would still work then, and it does.

So I'm very happy :)

Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Comment: Had this same issue, most of the sites to answer this issue are just way off track.  I think the user profile is possibly corrupted, as the default program would be selected, but every time it opens a file it asks again and again how to open it.